# Can I use multiple datastore on local machine with App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to run multiple Google App Engine's Datastore from my local machine in Python.

**UPDATED**
My problem is this:
When i run project-A on GAE locally.
It is working fine.
But When run project-B the datastore of project-A are alerady gone
So, how can i run multiple GAE project locally.

Comment: What do you mean with "deploy multiple GAE project locally"? 
Deploying is when you 'upload' the project to GAE, but locally means that you run it in your machine. Which are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry. i was wrong. I updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

To run different applications locally with independent datastore, you need to execute `dev_appserver.py` in different terminal sessions.

In each execution you need to specify different `--admin_port`, `--port`, and `--storage_path` flags so both apps can run independent to one another.

Example:

```
Session 1 $ dev_appserver.py <location1-to-app.yaml>/app.yaml
--admin_port=<ADMIN_PORT1> --port=<PORT1> --storage_path=<Path1> 

Sesison 2 $ dev_appserver.py <location2-to-app.yaml>/app.yaml
--admin_port=<ADMIN_PORT2> --port=<PORT2> --storage_path=<Path2>
```

This will create different datastore files in each path.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/local-devserver-command)’s information about `dev_appserver.py` flags you may find useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly specify projectId on datastore connection object creation.

Example in nodejs:

**Project-A**

```
const db = new Datastore({
    projectId: "google-project-A-id"
});
```

**Project-B**

```
const db = new Datastore({
    projectId: "google-project-B-id"
});
```

You can setup this via configs, so you will not need to hardcode it.
In this case each datastore connection in application will always point to specific project's datastore instance.

See how to pass projectId into Datastore class for your language in documentation.

Comment: So, in this case, it should be `datastore.Client("project-A")` in project-A and `datastore.Client("project-B")` in project-B. A example in here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-python/blob/master/2-structured-data/bookshelf/model_datastore.py